# Show System Tray Notify Message for the current logged in user?

Tags: c#, notifyicon

I have a Windows Desktop Application that needs to display a system Tray notification message for the current logged in user although the application may have been run by another user that previously logged in to windows and started the application?

What do i need to do to make this happen?
Currently the notification appears but only for the user who started the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is de-couple the desktop application from the alerts. Because the second user has not started the application they will not have the tray icon running. What you could do is create a new executable that runs constantly (on Windows start-up) that simply shows the tray-icon and notifies users of their alerts. That way the desktop application could just register the events and all / any instances of the tray application can show them.